# How to copy shortcut into an xml file from batch file?

Tags: batch-file

i have a batch file to add shortcut application in startup menu , this batch file work finely but i don't get the access under a specific file to add it.

Here the code :

```
@echo off
  xcopy /y "C:\_MIT\Phoenix\PhoenixLoader.lnk" "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
```

I want  to add the shortcut "PhoenixLoader.lnk" in the " C:\ProgramData\startlayout\uppc.xml " file
uppc.xml file code :

```
<LayoutModificationTemplate 
xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" 
xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
<LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
 <DefaultLayoutOverride>
<StartLayoutCollection>
  <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6">
    <start:Group Name="UPPC">
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\App1.lnk" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\App2.lnk" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="0" 
     </start:Group>
  </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
</StartLayoutCollection>
```

I have to access the file uppc.xml and add " PhoenixLoader.lnk " in the first line of the code instead of app1.lnk :

```
 DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start 
 Menu\Programs\PhoenixLoader.lnk"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q74147544.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

SET "replace=app1.lnk"
SET "replacement=PhoenixLoader.lnk"

(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%b"
 ECHO !line:%replace%=%replacement%!
)
)>"%outfile%"

FC "%filename1%" "%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

I tested with a file called `q74147544.txt` containing a copy of the `uppc.xml` file you posted.

The resultant file in `outfile.txt` was :

```
<LayoutModificationTemplate 
xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" 
xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
<LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
 <DefaultLayoutOverride>
<StartLayoutCollection>
  <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6">
    <start:Group Name="UPPC">
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PhoenixLoader.lnk" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\App2.lnk" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="0" 
     </start:Group>
  </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
</StartLayoutCollection>
```

You would need to move this file as appropriate for your installation, but the file used as the source file must be different from the file used as the destination file.

Essentially, read each line of the source ino `%%b`, then move `%%b` to a user-variable (`line`) for manipulation as string-substitution cannot be applied to `%%b`.

The string substitution is to substitute the `replacement` string for the `replace` string. Since the value of `line` is being changed within the parenthesised `code block`, you require `delayedexpansion` - see [Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

The substitution semantics are described in the `set` help, accessible by executing `set /?` from the prompt.